# Validation in form create by $fieldset

Tags: magento2, fieldsets

How to add 2 or more validation in `$fieldset` when create.
Example:

```
        $fieldset->addField(
        'tax_class_id',
        'select',
        [
            'name' => 'tax_class',
            'label' => __('Tax Class'),
            'title' => __('Tax Class'),
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'required' => true,
            'values' => 'test',
        ]
    );
```

And how to know which is the first validation will check. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'tax_class_id',
    'select',
    [
        'name' => 'tax_class',
        'label' => __('Tax Class'),
        'title' => __('Tax Class'),
        'class' => 'validate-email validate-digits required-entry', //add multiple classess
        'required' => true,
        'values' => 'test',
    ]
);
```

The class `required-entry` always gets first preference then validation is checked in order of classes added. You can try with `validate-email validate-digits required-entry`.
[This](http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/) is reference for available classes.

Answer (score 3):

You may to add new validations to 'class' element separated with gap. E.g.:

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'tax_class_id',
    'select',
    [
        'name' => 'tax_class',
        'label' => __('Tax Class'),
        'title' => __('Tax Class'),
        'class' => 'required-entry validate-email validate-digits',
        'required' => true,
        'values' => 'test',
    ]
);
```

More examples you may find in Magento forms, e.g. `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Permissions\User\Edit\Tab\Main.php`